# Html Live notification technologies

Tags: html, web-services, push-notification, web-push

I would like to implement live notification functionality onto my website. When on the website, should the user receive an email, server stats exceeded certain parameters etc, and jquery notification box should appear on the users Webpage.

I have achieved this currently by using ajax and php on timers to query a mysql database however this is complety the wrong way to do this.

I have also written client - middleware - server programs in c# so am familiar with sockets, asynchronous callbacks etc.

What relevant technologies could I use for achieving functionality such as this?

Comment: [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) is a pretty good solution for this. It provides a selection of middleware (including web sockets) and tries to abstract away those concerns for you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to use webSockets for this because they allow a continuous connection between a browser client and server so that the server can send a live notification to the client at any time.  All modern browsers support webSocket connections and, because they initiate on port 80 by default, they are generally compatible with existing client, server and networking infrastructure and existing browser security policies.

If you use a webSocket library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), it offers fallbacks to other methods (such as HTTP polling) in case a direct webSocket connection cannot be established.  But, if you use `socket.io`, then you need socket.io support on both client and server as it is a  higher level protocol on top of webSockets (or other transports).